# Tag wiki rendering is not the same as the "rendered output" shown in the edit review

Tags: bug, review-queues, tag-wiki

I was just going through the review queue and picked up this suggested edit to the "field" tag wiki: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5909137

I wondered why the editor thought they were fixing a b0rked bracket when clearly the link has rendered fine, brackets and all - and I verified by clicking on it that it goes to the right place.

However as you can see from the screenshot, if I view the actual tag wiki itself, the trailing bracket is indeed b0rked.

I think the rendering in the review view ought to be the same as in the tag wiki itself....!

[image: Review view]

[image: tag wiki view]

Comment: Previous revision is ~2 years old, some bugs have been fixed in the renderer since then. Wouldn't be surprised if the suggested edit view re-renders it (for the highlights). (i.e. a null edit would have fixed it.)

Comment: I've been going through the latest data dump to find bad Wikipedia links. I just scanned for links to en.wikipedia.org, and hit everything against the Wikipedia API to look for missing articles, redirects, disambiguation pages, etc.  The link was bad in the rendered HTML that is provided.