# Rendered output of review suggestion is incorrect

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

This review edit is actually showing the incorrect output of the answer in question.  The reviewer's edit was rejected even though it is something I would normally approve of.

Suggested Edit Page With Error: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8631953

Actual Answer: [How do I call a jq function from vb.net code behind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834030/how-do-i-call-a-jq-function-from-vb-net-code-behind/3834061#3834061)

Bug: The code in between `<% %>` asp.NET brackets does not appear correctly on the suggested edit page.  This may be a similar bug as [Tag wiki rendering is not the same as the "rendered output" shown in the edit review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272688/tag-wiki-rendering-is-not-the-same-as-the-rendered-output-shown-in-the-edit-re) but seems more significant.

Edit:
The question was edited again.  Here was the original answer

> in your aspx page do this <% if (Request.QueryString["var"].ToString()
>   == "Hide") { %> function guestHide() { $(".panel").hide("slow"); } <% } %>
>
> The above is C#, it should be easily translatable to VB.

However in the suggested review section, only this appeared.

> in your aspx page do this
>
> function guestHide() { $(".panel").hide("slow"); } The above is C#, it
>   should be easily translatable to VB

This is bug is in Chrome 43.0.2357.130 m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No code was not showing correctly in the [first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3834061/1).  If the reviewers would have switch to viewing the markdown instead of the the rendered view they would have seen that the code was there originally and only need to be indented to make a code block.

Comment: I see, this make sense and I guess is why the code markdown "Code Sample" markdown exists.  But stuff in between <% %> does not show where it does show in suggested edits where it does show in the answer.  Which makes it very confusing for the reviewers.

Comment: Those three reviewers who really should take a break.

Comment: @Deduplicator That they should.  I could tell right from the rendered output what was going on and just had to click on the markdown to confirm.  I would never have rejected that edit.